# Using readline module in node.js, how do I ask a certain number of questions, but not ask the next question before previous answer is received

Tags: node.js, readline

For example, if this is my code

```
var rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout,
    terminal: false,
});

for(var i = 0;i<7;i++){
    rl.question('What is your name? ', function(name){
        console.log("Your name is " + name);
    });
}
```

then when I run it in the CLI what I am prompted is

```
What is your name?What is your name?What is your name?What is your name?What is your name?What is your name?What is your name?
```

How do I make it such that it asks "What is your name?", then gets an answer, then displays the output, and then repeats this 6 more times.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

By default, the `question` method is callback-based. Meaning that in order to ask the second question, you'll need to call the 2nd `rl.question` inside the callback of the first `question` call.

This approach is very brittle and won't scale at all in your case because you would end up with a deep pyramid of nested callbacks.

So, one strategy could be to turned this callback-based API into a promise-based one. Fortunately, Node.js offer a handy `promisify` helper available in the `util` module that can perform this transformation.

This is detailed in the official doc: https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v15.x/docs/api/readline.html

With this new promisified `question` function returning a promise, you can now use the `async`/`await` syntax to obtain what you expect:

```js
var readline = require('readline');
var util = require('util');

var rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout,
    terminal: false
});

var question = util.promisify(rl.question).bind(rl);

async function ask() {
    for(var i = 0;i<7;i++){
        try {
            var name = await question('What is you name? ');
            console.log("Your name is " + name);
        } catch (err) {
            console.error('Question rejected', err);
        }
    }
    rl.close();
}

ask()
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for the response. I tried that out, and although the seqencing works correctly right now where the next question is asked after the previous response, what happens now is that it catches all responses as an error (input and output shown below)
`What is you name? temp
Question rejected temp`
How do you suggest this issue should be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

[`util.promisify`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v14.x/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original) gets you close, but it expects a function of two arguments: An error and a value. `rl.question` does not satisfy this interface: it always calls the function with one argument which is the input. `util.promisify` sees this input as non-null and hence assumes an error occurred.

Fortunately, `util.promisify` is a super simple function and we can rewrite it ourselves to work in this use case.

```
const question = (...args) => new Promise((res, rej) => rl.question(...args, res));
```

Now `question` is a function which produces a promise. We can async it. The rest of the code works as in Delapouite's answer

```
async function ask() {
    for(var i = 0;i<7;i++){
        try {
            var name = await question('What is you name? ');
            console.log("Your name is " + name);
        } catch (err) {
            console.error('Question rejected', err);
        }
    }
    rl.close();
}

ask()
```